# Getting Start of ID Number in specific date format

Tags: c#

Lets say I have this ID number that starts with: 911125...

91 = 1991(year) 
11 = November(month) 
25 = day(day)

How can I get this in this format: 25 November 1991?

EDIT: this is what I have tried, but I know this is wrong:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What does  91125 represent?   January 25, 1991 or December 5?

Comment: Does your date always reside in the first 6 digits?

Comment: Why do you think what you have tried is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse it to `DateTime` object (*[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)*) and then  you can format it like:

```
string str = "911125";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str
                            , "yyMMdd"
                            , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                            , DateTimeStyles.None
                            , out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date string");
}
```

and you will get:

```
25 November 1991
```

EDIT:

Your code should work fine, it is parsing the `Date`, but you are not formatting it for displaying.

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

The reason I have used `DateTime.TryParseExact` is that it doesn't throw an exception if the parsing failed. `DateTime.ParseExact` would do the same job except it would throw an exception if the string passed to it doesn't match the format provided.